# iOS 13 AASA file not downloading

Tags: ios, ios13, ios-universal-links, aasa

I noticed that the AASA file is not downloaded (by monitoring the API calls in Charles) on iOS 13.1. 
I was going through the WWDC https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/717/ video, but could not find any hint whether we need an additional step on iOS 13.

Anyone experienced the same problem?
It works on iOS 12.2 and earlier.

Answer (score 3):

i was facing this same issue. I found that was charles root certificate the cause of the AASA file not being downloaded. After I removed it from my device, AASA file was downloaded again and universal links worked fine.

Comment: could you please share how you were managed to remove Charles root certificate? Looks like on iOS 13 we don't have that section at Settings app.

Comment: I removed from the Profiles option in Settings -> General -> Profiles

Answer (score 0):

You can check in your console for error if any during file download on first installation 
https://ios13.dev/universal-links-debugging-on-ios-13-cjwsux93w001p6ws1swtstmzc

And if you want to validate JSON format
https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/